# How to add inappbrowser.js and cordova.js to web app to make window.open to work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

We have native shell written using `cordova android`.

Web app is being callled from `MainActivity` using `loadurl(webapp url)`

From webapp we open certain links using `window.open`

How do I use `inappbrowser` to open those links?

**Where should be `cordova.js` and `inappbrowser.js` be added?**

Comment: `cordova.js` and `inappbrowser.js` will be automatically added when you add the platform and plugins. What you should is : `cordova platform add android`, `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, `cordova run android`

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply. I have followed same steps. When I call window.open(url, _self) from webapp javscript code, Control is going to inappbrowser and cordova.js files. Control comes till nativeapprovider.get().exec(some parameter related to service url arguments) after that it should actually hit OnLoadResources method in native. Control does not come in there, Please help if I have missed any thing which binds web and native